# How to tagging groups to yammer conversion

Tags: tags, yammer

Can we tag (using @) more than one groups to a post so the every one in the group will get notification. Can we do that programatically?

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking for is not currently possible, since it would require posting a message to multiple groups, which is not currently supported (source: I work at Yammer). If you think this feature would be valuable to you, I'd encourage you to support the respective suggestion on UserVoice (https://yammer.uservoice.com/forums/399627-yammer/suggestions/15625800-post-a-thread-to-multiple-groups) -- we look at UserVoice regularly as input for which new features we build for Yammer.

What you could do programmatically as a (somewhat ugly) workaround currently is to get all the users of the second group and CC them (or @mention them) on the message to the first group. You can get the users of the second group using the REST API endpoint /users/in_group/[:id].json -- see https://developer.yammer.com/docs/usersin_groupidjson

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can:

1. Post your message to one group (one you consider to be the main group)
2. Afterwards, click the "Share" link and select another group to which you want to cross-post the message

   [image]

Dokumentation:

- https://support.office.com/en-us/article/classic-yammer-share-conversations-and-files-in-yammer-2c69c57d-2605-4047-830c-089bb41b08bb?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US